# this.method is not a function, binding not working

Tags: javascript

Probably is a really simple problem but cannot find what's going on here, this is my case:

I have a method of the class "ProjectBox" that is triggered on a drop event. This method creates a modal and attach an event listener to a button inside the modal.

When that button is pressed, it emits to the server some data and performs a class method when callback is done.

I'm having the problem on that call to the class method, i'm attaching code down:

```
ProjectBox.prototype.handleDrop = function (e) {

// some code to create the modal

// function to attach to the event of button clicked ->
var choose_project_role_event =  ()=> {

        socket.emit( 'addProjectMember', {project_member: dragged_user, project_id: e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id, role: select_typeof_member.value  }, ( reply )=> {

            if ( reply.response ) {
                this.printMember( reply.member_data )
            }
        })
    }
    choose_role_send.addEventListener( 'click', choose_project_role_event)
}

ProjectBox.prototype.printMember = function ( params ) {
```

```
app.js:1145 Uncaught TypeError: this.printMember is not a function
```

I've read that arrow functions doesn't need to use .bind( this ) to solve scope problems, but I've even modified the code to be anonymous functions and perform the binding but I still having the same issue.

What is going on here? I'm pretty lost on this one.

Comment: It isn't clear what you expect `this` to be. Possibly an instance of `ProjectBox` but I've no idea how that is supposed to be connected to `choose_project_role_event`

Comment: @Quentin Is the reference to the class ProjectBox, wich contains the function of the first code snippet and the problematic one.

Comment: *How* does it contain the first code snippet? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: How are you creating the instance of `ProjectBox`? How are you calling `handleDrop`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a function scope problem. The arrow function scope will take the scope of the outer function, in this case that will be `window` because the `choose_project_role_event` is defined on global scope and not inside a object/function scope.

If you want `choose_project_role_event` to have access to the instance members, in this case `printMember`, you should define the function inside the prototype of the `ProjectBox` class.

Comment: My bad for not explaining it better, but the arrow functions are inside of a method of the class, unless I understood you wrong, nothing should be on global scope on this problem.

Comment: Why `choose_project_role_event ` is not attached to `ProjectBox.prototype` then?

Comment: Then it's a probability you're calling `choose_project_role_event` as a callback for another modal event (at "some code to create the modal" level), hence binding it to another scope, other than `ProjectBox`.